# How to find the anchor text from Web Element located using CSS Locator?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have a list of anchors in HTML page with id, href, etc attributes.

```
<a id="vRecords534534_link" onclick="theEvent=event;openModal(this.href, {width: 640});return false;" href="https://example/sourceDetailAction.do?NoticeId=534615198&webFlow=gcaMain">SIXER</a>

<a id="vRecords64353_link" onclick="theEvent=event;openModal(this.href, {width: 640});return false;" href="https://example/sourceDetailAction.do?NoticeId=534615198&webFlow=gcaMain">CROSS</a>
```

and so on. Look at the id attribute having starting and ending text.

I used CSS Locator to do this:

```
@FindBy(how=How.CSS, using="a[id^='vRecords'][id$='link']")
protected List<WebElement> vRecordsList;

public void getVendorRecordList(){
        System.out.println(vRecordsList.size());

        for(WebElement s : vRecordsList){
            System.out.println("Record List ::"+s.getAttribute("value"));
        }
}
```

From the above code, I am able to find all the ids stars-with with **vRecords** and ends-with **link**.

**Problem :** From this, i want to get the anchor value for each link like "**SIXER**", "**CROSS**" from the anchor links above.

If any other approach is feasible, then also revert.

Comment: Please reply. Is this feasible to do this or some other way/approach is required.

Comment: And what is the problem with what you have?

Comment: Using `.getText()` should work... what error are you getting?

Comment: @Robot please come back try with updated answer and if helped accept the answer and mark this question as solved...:)

Answer (score 0):

`getAttribute` basically use for getting the element attribute property. But here you want to get the text inside `a`. So achieving this there is a method `getText()` Provided by selenium as below :-

```
  for(WebElement s : vRecordsList){
        System.out.println("Record List ::"+s.getText());
   }
```

**Edited** :- If unfortunately `getText()` does not work here try using `getAttribute("innerHTML")` as below :-

```
   for(WebElement s : vRecordsList){
        System.out.println("Record List ::"+s.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
   }
```

Or using `getAttribute("textContent")` as below :-

```
for(WebElement s : vRecordsList){
        System.out.println("Record List ::"+s.getAttribute("textContent"));
   }
```

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: @Robot try with updated answer hope be it helps...:)